# Airflow get/set a parameter on BashOperator

Tags: python, bash, airflow

I'm trying to set a value as parameter and later use it on bashOperations. It is failing because I don't know how to use task_instance.xcom_pull. Please help me to get/set a parameter in the bash string.

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id = 'stackover',
    schedule_interval='01 6 * * *',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='stackover',
    tags=['stackover'],
    catchup=False
)

week_op = BashOperator(
    task_id="week_op",
    bash_command='echo "{{ params.week }}"',
    params = {'week' : ' $(date +%V -d \"1 week ago\") ',},
    provide_context=True,
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag
)


start_op = BashOperator(
    task_id="start_op",
    bash_command=' {{ params.query }}"',
    params = {'query' : 'echo {{ (task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids=\'week_op\')) }} ',},
    provide_context=True,
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag
)

week_op >> start_op
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jinja directly in `bash_command` as:

```
start_op = BashOperator(
    task_id="start_op",
    bash_command=' echo {{ ti.xcom_pull("week_op") }}',
    provide_context=True,
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So I can not use Jinja on params ? There is no way around to use it on params? or to use at the same time params and Jinja ?

Comment: `params` is not templated argument. So you can't do that. I'm not sure why you even need this. But if you really must have this you can create your custom operator that inherit from `BaseOpertor` and add `params` argument to the list of `template_fields`

Comment: Is there a way to prevent Jinja from leaving a space infront ? I can not get echo46, only echo 46

Comment: I believe you should be able to set it with the Jinja settings. you can control over it from `jinja_environment_kwargs` argument of DAG

Comment: I'm trying but I can't remove the white space . https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html
lstrip_blocks
https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/api/#jinja2.Environment